# CSS Issue with aligning panels within panels

Tags: html, css, alignment

Take a look at the image below. 
I defined the red boxes inside the blue box however they drift left into the black box.
Interestingly enoguh, in older browsers or with compatibility mode checked, they look the way I want them to. It also looks the way I wish it to look in VS2008. Does any one have any ideas? Here is the CSS

```
body
{
}
.left
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 750px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: small;
}

.right
{
    border: solid 1px blue;
    width: 750px;
    height: 750px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: small;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to include the HTML as well. Also can you trim that image a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, I also need a float: left in .right
I wonder why this though.